# Magento 2 : Issue with the custom field on checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods, magento2.1.0, custom-field

Installed Version of Magento is - **2.1.0**

I have added a custom field "**Bank Account Number**" as you can see red square box in the below image.

[image]

The problem I am facing is that it's not getting displayed in the summary as shown in below image.

[image]

Comment: Do you need to add a field to customer address?

Comment: @SergeyIvashchenko : I have updated my question . So let me know the possible solution here...Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The next template is responsible for rendering this summary block:

`module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html`

**How to override:**

1. From Theme. File located by following path will override mentioned template:

`app/design/frontend/YourTheme/default/Magento_Checkout/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html`

2. From Module. Using RequireJs configuration:

Create `app/code/YourNamespace/YourModule/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js` in the module that is dependent on Magento_Checkout (has Magento_Checkout in sequence in module.xml) with the following content:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer/default': 'YourNamespace_YouModule/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer/default'
        }
    }
};
```

And create corresponding template file in your module.

See more information about template customization in [Magento 2 Frontend Development Guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/bk-frontend-dev-guide.html)

**How to render address attribute:**

Address attribute in this particular block should be rendered by knockout.js, here is the basic example of syntax to render the attribute string:

```
<!-- ko text: address().yourattribute --><!-- /ko -->
```

See more information about knockout.js rendering in [Knockout.js documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html).

Comment: How to get value of this.address() in default.js file? In js file no address function is defined. please let me know hot this value is getting in above default.js file?